# What's the Vue lifecycle chronology between components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a `<router-view>` showing one component (A) and through a `<router-link>` this component will be replaced by another one (B).

Both components have their own `beforeCreate` and `beforeDestroy` hooks. I'd expect that if I navigated from A to B the sequence of events would be:

1. `A.beforeDestroy`
2. `B.beforeCreate`

But after doing some tests it appears to be the exact opposite: `B.beforeCreate` is always called **before** `A.beforeDestroy`.

Is that correct? And if it's correct, why is it this way? Doesn't make sense to me...

In my case all those hooks interact with some common data, so I'm facing race conditions here... Any suggestion on how to deal with that? I need to get some things done before creating B that cannot be started before destroying A...

Comment: as [Vue Github for patch.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/patch.js#L685) and [VUe Github for lifecycle](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L50), Vue will create new vnode first, then remove old vnode at the end. the problem you described, probably uses [vue-router navigator](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) will be one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the previous component is destroyed, the next component will be created first.
The purpose is obviously to avoid flickering as the view transitions from the previous component to the next component.

If the behavior you wanted is to make sure that a code should be executed always **after** the `beforeDestroy` and not **before**, you should use the `mounted` or `beforeMount` lifecycle hook.